# Puppet 2.7.x - Global variable - Append

Tags: linux, nginx, puppet

Without getting to far into the weeds, Nginx is forcing my hand in order to accomplish some magic with vhosts and the `map` directive.

Is there an elegant (relative) solution to sharing a variable across multiple define calls, which allows each define call to append it's data to the global variable? In software this would be known as a singleton.

**-- The weeds --**

Nginx has a `map` directive which dictates which upstream server pool the request should be passed to, like so:

```
map $http_host $upstream_pool {

    hostnames;

    blog.example.com     blog_example_com;
    repo.example.com     repo_example_com;

    default example_com;
}
```

As you can see, any requests for blog.example.com will be passed to the blog_example_com upstream server pool (by way of `proxy_pass`).

The problem is the `map` directive syntax is that it can only be included within the main `http` block (nginx.conf), whereas vhost specific directives such as `upstream` and `location` can be included in the `server` block of a vhost config.

My nodes.pp manifest looks something like this:

```
 service-a-1.example.com inherits project_dev {

     nginx::vhost { 'mothership': }
     nginx::vhost { 'mothership_blog': }
     nginx::vhost { 'repo': }
}
```

As you can see, after a successful puppet run, I should end up with 3 distinct vhost config files in `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/` dir.

The problem I am having is that in order for the `map` directive to work, I need to know which vhosts were loaded, so I can add their respective upstream ids to the `map` directive, which I have defined in the primary config: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` within the `http` block (of which there can only be one).

**-- What I have tried -**-

I have a global.pp file which does some "bootstrapping" and in this file I added a `$singleton = ''` syntax, then in the nginx::vhost define, I added this syntax:

```
$tpl_upstream_pool_labels = inline_template("<% tpl_upstream_pools.keys.sort.each do |role| %><%= role %>_<%= tpl_domain_primary %>_<%= tpl_domain_top_level %>|<% end %>")

$singleton = "${singleton}${tpl_upstream_pool_labels}"

notify { "\n--------------------- Nginx::Conf::Vhost::Touch | Timestamp: ${timestamp} | Pool labels: ${singleton} -------------------------\n": }
```

Which should result in a pipe delimited list of upstream ids. As mentioned earlier, in the nodes.pp manifest, I make three calls to nginx::vhost, and would expect the `$singleton` global variable to be appended for every call, however it is not, it only contains the last call's data.

I also tried to hack my way around this by writing a temp file like so:

```
$temp_file_upstream_pool_labels_uri = "/tmp/puppet_known_upstreams_${timestamp}.txt"

exec { "event_record_known_upstream_${name}" :            
    command     => "touch ${temp_file_upstream_pool_labels_uri} && echo ${tpl_upstream_pool_labels} >> ${temp_file_upstream_pool_labels_uri}",            
    provider    => 'shell'
}
```

Then in the nginx::conf::touch define, where the primary config nginx.conf is to be written by puppet, I tried this:

```
$temp_file_upstream_pool_labels_uri = "/tmp/puppet_known_upstreams_${timestamp}.txt"

$contents = file($temp_file_upstream_pool_labels_uri)
```

Which should, in theory, load the contents of the file into the $contents variable. But when I run puppet using this approach I get an error that the file does not exist. I ensured that the nginx::conf::touch call is not made until after all the vhosts were considered, but still to no avail.

Comment: Question is straight forward, however in the interests of solving my problem, I also included 'the weeds'.

Comment: OK, _now_ your question makes sense. From what I understand, the usual solution for this is [concat](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat), though I have no experience with it myself.

Comment: Concat looks promising, however it's only for 3.x, and I am currently on 2.7.x

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think 2.7.x is supported anymore. Might be time to upgrade.

Comment: Lol. And spend another 3-4 months porting over all the modules? Don't have that kind of time nor resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with global variables in Puppet is that you cannot actually append to them. The `+=` syntax is allowed, but it creates a **local copy** of the global, with the right hand side value appended.

I have implemented a pattern that does what you want, but I'm not proud of it and cannot recommend using it. Still, since you're asking, here goes:

```
class nginx::conf {
    $global = ''
    file { '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf':
        content => template(...)
    }
}
```

The variable from the class *can* be appended, at least in `2.7.x`.

```
define nginx::vhost(...) {
    include nginx::conf

    $nginx::conf::global += "new content here"
    nginx::override_conf_content { "for-vhost-$name": }
}
```

The magic happens in the mysterious final line, which instantiates yet another `define`.

```
define nginx::override_conf_content() {
    include nginx::conf
    $global = $nginx::conf::global
    File<| title == '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' |> { 
        content => template(...)
    }
}
```

The `content` property for `nginx.conf` is overridden with the result of another evaluation of the template, with the new variable value.

Full disclosure, I'm not sure why this works. It probably shouldn't, and may rely on an obscure bug. It may stop working in future versions.

Note that I called it `$global` instead of `$singleton`, because that's what it is. Singletons can be used to implement the semantics of globals, but they are not the same thing.

Finally, even though I can feel your pain facing the Puppet 3 update, you should really take the time and get it underway. We all will likely not be able to afford running `2.x` much longer.

Comment: Interesting. I ended up having to add a static mapping for `dev` and `prod` pools to a config.yaml file just to get past the issue and move onto bigger things. Puppet and I have a love / hate relationship; I love that it keeps servers in check, but I hate the fact that simple design principles are not avail.  I get that it's based upon DSL, and being a software guy I am procedural based, but 2.7 should have at least afforded us the ability to accomplish these simple feats. Moving onto puppet 3.x will be a huge undertaking, but if we get funded, I think we can make it happen. Thx for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer to keep the issues separate.

The approach that combines `exec` and `file()` is flawed because those work on very different levels.

The `exec` resource is added to the catalog and sent to the agent, where it is evaluated after compiling has finished. Since you are trying to gather information *during* compile time (before you collect it using the `file()` function), you cannot rely on any resources.

It should be possible to build what you have in mind by relying on the [generate](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#generate) function instead of `exec` resources.

Comment: Confirmed. When I tried to write to a file, the contents wouldn't be available until I ran it a 2nd time. Then I started running into permission issues (SELinux enabled), so then I decided to create an empty file in the modules/nginx/files dir, but this made no sense as I now had a file whose sole purpose was to act as a container for transitory data. In short, total hack.